# Is sudo killall -u lightdm safe?

Tags: sudo, lightdm, process, killall

I realized that my server has many processes runned by `lightdm`:

[image]

**Can i killall processes from lightdm?**

**Is `sudo killall -u lightdm` safe?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lightdm is the X display manager for Ubuntu and killing the processes will effectively disable the graphical user interface of your system. If you do not need the graphical user interface then go ahead and kill the processes but it would be preferable to stop the lightdm service instead of killing the processes with:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Additionally, if you want to restart lightdm and you are on a local machine you can do it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> on your keyboard to access the TTY, login with your username and password and enter the command below or if you are remotely connected simply run the command through SSH.

```
sudo service lightdm start
```